# Add tab bar & navigation bar in Window based application iPhone

Tags: iphone

Hi guys
I am new to iphone app development. I want to develop a application which contains tab bar ,navigation bar & middle part of view contains UIImageView.
When my application will launch it will show main view .On main view I want to add "Loading view " for connecting to server which contains text (Connecting.. & so on) & activity indicator, like this view pointed by red arrow =>

http://img10.imageshack.us/i/16467623.jpg/

How can I add this view?

My app contains 4 tabs on main view in which last tab is more.
I completed tab bar part using tab bar controller as rootViewController .
How to add navigation bar ? I want navigation bar for whole app.
I mean to say when i select first tab new view will appear ,select 2nd tab => new view & so on. I want navigation bar & back button for all tabs so that I can return to my main screen containing all 4 tabs .
Also i want to hide my tab bar when i select tab bar item & animated to new view.

Please help me guys. Any links to tutorial , code or video is more helpful...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please comment on answers rather than adding your own answers as replies. This is not a forum. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this video tutorial. It covers a lot and should get you on your way.

Pause it, replay some parts, whatever works.

[Building an iPhone App Combining Tab Bar, Navigation and Tab O'REILLY](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBnPfAtswgw)

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is the View Controller Programming Guide and the section on [Tab Bar Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TabBarControllers/TabBarControllers.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH102-SW1). This is Apple documentation and the guide has step-by-step instructions in implementing different view controllers. You should also read the chapter on `UINavigationController`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a tab bar and a navigation bar simultaneously in a not tabbed view application, just create a UIViewController subclass, add a Tab Bar in the view, add its tab bar items and set a delegate to File´s Owner and a referencing outlet to File´s owner. For the last one, write in the .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MyView : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UITabBar *tabBarController;
}
@end
```